# Showing this increasing sequence with $x_{3m}=m$ tends to infinity

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be an increasing sequence with the property that $x_{3m}=m$ for all $m\in\mathbb{N}$. I need to show that $(x_n)$ tends to infinity using the following definition:
$$\forall \varepsilon>0\exists N\in\mathbb{N} (n>N \implies x_n>\varepsilon). $$ I only got as far as noticing that any $x_n\in \{x_{3m},x_{3m-1},x_{3m-2}\}$ for some integer $m$, and so for such an $m$, we know $x_n\geq m$, but I can't see how to choose $N$ or how to proceed otherwise.

Update: With help from the comments, I realised what I was doing wrong. You choose $N=3m$ for some $m\in \mathbb{N}$ where $m>\varepsilon$, so if $n>N$, then $x_n\geq x_N = x_{3m} =m>\varepsilon$.

Comment: You are probably reading $x_{3m}=m$ as $x_{3m}=x_m$.

Comment: Choose $~m~$ such that $~3m > \epsilon.~$  Then, for all $~n \geq 3m,~$ you have that $~x_n \geq x_{3m} > \epsilon.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

For every $\epsilon=m$, when can you say that $n>N_\epsilon$ implies $x_n\geq m= \epsilon$?

How can you extrapolate from this for all $\epsilon>0$?